# How to fix 'One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)'?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created web api, when trying to add ssl get this error, when the code try to reach an endpoint in the web api i get this error, this is a self-signed certificates.

This is development environment, using visual studio 2019 to debug the code but no luck after trying to re-create the ssl certificates, checked guides about implement https in .net core apps, yet no luck.

Program.cs:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .UseSetting("https_port", "5001")
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {

                    options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5000);
                    options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5001,
                        listenOptions => { listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "A2345_678b"); });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SmartContext>();

             services.AddMvc(
                     options =>
                     {
                         options.SslPort = 5001;
                         options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

                     }
                 );
             services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
             {
                 options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
                 options.HttpsPort = 5001;
             });
             services.AddAntiforgery(
                     options =>
                     {
                         options.Cookie.Name = "_af";
                         options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                         options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

                         options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
                     }
                 );
             services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
             {
                 // Password settings
                 options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                 options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                 options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                 options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                 options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

             });
            services.AddDbContext<SmartContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 5):

All you should need to do is run the following in your project root:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This should pop a dialog asking you if you want to add the cert to your trusted store, which you obviously should accept. You'll need to do this for each project. For example, it's not enough to trust your web app, if that web app is connecting to an API app. You need to do the same thing for the API app so that both certs are trusted.